# I want to receive the result in JSON format using JSON.parse, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

The results I am currently receiving are as follows.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "aa",
            "parent_id": 8,
            "products": "[{\"name\": \"aaa\", \"type\": \"aaa\", \"saleRate\": null, \"salePrice\": null, \"description\": \"aaa\"}, {\"name\": \"aaa\", \"type\": \"aaa\", \"saleRate\": null, \"salePrice\": null, \"description\": \"aaa\"}, {\"name\": \"aaa\", \"type\": \"aaa\", \"saleRate\": null, \"salePrice\": null, \"description\": \"aaa\"}]"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to get the result like below.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "aa",
            "parent_id": 8,
            "products": [{
              "name": "aaa", 
              "type": "aaa", 
              "saleRate": null, 
              "salePrice": null, 
              "description": "aaa"
            },{
              "name": "aaa", 
              "type": "aaa", 
              "saleRate": null, 
              "salePrice": null, 
              "description": "aaa"
            },{
              "name": "aaa", 
              "type": "aaa", 
              "saleRate": null, 
              "salePrice": null, 
              "description": "aaa"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Data is imported from productsDao.js file using mysql query statement.

productsDao.js

```
SELECT c.name AS category, c.level AS categoryDepth,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          "name", p.name, 
          "description", p.description,
          "priceOrigin", p.price
        )
      ) AS products
    FROM products p
    JOIN category c ON c.id = p.category_id
    WHERE p.category_id = 10
    GROUP BY p.category_id
```

I tried the following using JSON.parse() in the productsController.js file:
productsController.js

```
const readCategory = async (categoryId) => {
  const categories = await categoryDao.readCategory(categoryId);
  return JSON.parse(categories);
};
```

But it is still unchanged. Any other solution? I want help.

Comment: `JSON.parse` does not return "JSON" ... it returns a javascript Object - it looks like `products` is JSON within JSON ... so perhaps ... you'll need to JSON.parse the `data.products` after you get the result of the first JSON.parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one liner solution would be

```
var obj = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "aa",
            "parent_id": 8,
            "products": "[{\"name\": \"aaa\", \"type\": \"aaa\", \"saleRate\": null, \"salePrice\": null, \"description\": \"aaa\"}, {\"name\": \"aaa\", \"type\": \"aaa\", \"saleRate\": null, \"salePrice\": null, \"description\": \"aaa\"}, {\"name\": \"aaa\", \"type\": \"aaa\", \"saleRate\": null, \"salePrice\": null, \"description\": \"aaa\"}]"
        }
    ]
}

obj.data.forEach(d => d.products = JSON.parse(d.products))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use JSON format, your problem is that the data within the `[...]` also needs to be in pairs, and grouped in `{...}`.
For better understanding check this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/json-stringify-example-how-to-parse-a-json-object-with-javascript/).

For instance,

```
{ 
   "sales": [ 
         { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Brown" },
         { "firstname" : "Marc", "lastname" : "Johnson" }
     ] // end of sales array
}
```

So you might have:

```
 {
     "COLUMNS": [ 
      {"REGISTRATION_DT" : "19901212", "USERNAME" : "kudos", "PASSWORD" : "tx91!#1", ... },
      {"REGISTRATION_DT" : "19940709", "USERNAME" : "jenny", "PASSWORD" : "fxuf#2", ... },
      {"REGISTRATION_DT" : "20070110", "USERNAME" : "benji12", "PASSWORD" : "rabbit19", ... }
     ]
 }
```

If the server is sending you something which you refer to as res, you can just do this to parse it in your Javascript:

```
var o=JSON.parse(res);
```

You can then cycle through each instance within columns like follows:

```
for (var i=0;i<o.COLUMNS.length;i++)
{  
        var date = o.COLUMNS[i].REGISTRATION_DT; .... 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you once try this?

```
const readCategory = async (categoryId) => {
  const categories = await categoryDao.readCategory(categoryId);
  categories.map((c) => {
  c.data.forEach((d) => {
    return {
      ...d,
      products:JSON.parse(d.products)
    }
  });
  });
  return categories;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model or entity with exact fields as your expected response, then map your response to the entity

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the JSON and run the `JSON.parse` on each `products` property.

```
let json_str = '{}'; // JSON from API
let json_obj = {};
try {
    json_obj = JSON.parse(json_str);
} catch (e) {
}
(json_obj['data'] || []).forEach(function(element, index) {
    if (typeof element['products'] === 'string') {
        try {
            element['products'] = JSON.parse(element['products']);
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
    json_obj['data'][index] = element;
});
```